# How to correctly instantiate a static HttpClient in constructor

Tags: c#, locking, httpclient

I have a custom [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netstandard-2.0) implementation that needs some values from my configuration to work properly.

```
public class MyHttpClient : HttpClient
{
    public MyHttpClient()
    {
    }

    public MyHttpClient(string token)
    {
        Token = token;
    }

    public string Token { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

I now want to use this HttpClient in my application logic that uses `IOptions<TOptions>` for getting its configuration.

```
public class MyLogic
{
    private static MyHttpClient Client;

    public MyLogic(IOptions<MyConfig> config)
    {
        // How to instantiate Client with values from config?
    }
}
```

Since HttpClient [should be held as a static field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netstandard-2.0#remarks), I struggle with the method I can inject the config value into the HttpClient. I came up with a few possibilities, but none of them seems to be fine.

**Option 1**: *set config value each time*

```
public class MyLogic
{
    private static MyHttpClient Client = new MyHttpClient();

    public MyLogic(IOptions<MyConfig> config)
    {
        Client.Token = config.Value.Token;
    }
}
```

This seems to be the worst option, since the value of `Token` may change as the HttpClient uses it.

**Option 2**: *lock each time*

```
public class MyLogic
{
    private static MyHttpClient Client;
    private static readonly object ClientLock = new object();

    public MyLogic(IOptions<MyConfig> config)
    {
        lock(ClientLock)
        {
            if (Client == null)
            {
                Client = new MyHttpClient(config.Value.Token);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to be bad from a performance perspective, since each instantiation of `MyLogic` would create a lock and block all others.

**Option 3**: *double-checked locking*

```
public class MyLogic
{
    private static volatile MyHttpClient Client;
    private static readonly object ClientLock = new object();

    public MyLogic(IOptions<MyConfig> config)
    {
        if (Client == null)
        {
            lock(ClientLock)
            {
                if (Client == null)
                {
                    Client = new MyHttpClient(config.Value.Token);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This seems like the solution, however double-checked locks are hard to get right and should therefore be avoided.

Sadly, [Lazy<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netstandard-2.0) doesn't seem to be an option since it also requires a static context for instance creation.

So, what would be the best option to instantiate the HttpClient in this situation?

Comment: Isn't this what [HttpClientFactory](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HttpClientFactoryForTypedHttpClientInstancesInASPNETCore21.aspx) was designed to help with? (And by "this" I meant "this problem space", not "how you're trying to solve this same problem")

Comment: This looks promising, however, since the project is a .NET Standard 2.0 class library, I'm not able to rely on DI inside the library.

Answer (score 0):

@Damien_The_Unbeliever :

Since I can not add a comment, I have to do a "full reply": 
The question goes into the direction, of how I can make sure that the HttpClient instance inside the shared project (which is neither Android nor iOS specific) correctly selects the Android `HttpClient` implementation when the App runs on an Android device.